# How can I add/remove files dynamically in an MVC view

Tags: c#, html, .net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I am working on a create view to add a number of files and save in the database. My models are as below.

```
public class WebEmail
{
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PdfFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] pdfSource { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public List<WebAsset> LstWebAssets { get; set; }
}

public class WebAsset
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreview { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PdfFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] pdfSource { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to post the Child content to the controller.

Here is the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create(WebEmail Email)
    {
        var files = Request.Files;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(Email);
        }
    }
```

I am using javascript to add/remove the files in the view. Here is how I have implemented it to capture the files:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Upload Files", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div id="uploads" class="row" style="margin:auto;">
            @foreach (var item in Model.LstWebAssets)
            {
                <div class="radio col-sm-2" id="uploadtemplate">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => item.IsPreview,true, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "radio" })
                    <input type="radio" name="IsPreview" checked>
                    <input type="file" id="inputPdf" name="PdfFile" accept="application/pdf" />
                </div>
            }                

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="DynamicFileInput(this.parentNode)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript code:

```
function DynamicFileInput(addbtn) {
var division = document.createElement('DIV');
division.innerHTML = AddDynamicInput();    
document.getElementById("uploads").insertBefore(division, addbtn);
```

}

```
function AddDynamicInput() {
return `<div class="radio col-sm-2" id="uploadtemplate">
            <input type="radio" name="IsPreview">
            <input type="file" id="inputPdf" name="PdfFile" accept="application/pdf" />
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnDelete" value="-" onclick="DeleteInput(this)" />
        </div>`;
```

}

```
function DeleteInput(thisButton) {
//$('#uploads').remove(thisButton.parent.parent);
document.getElementById("uploads").removeChild(thisButton.parentNode.parentNode);
```

}

This code allows me to add or remove a file in the view, but when I try to post to the controller, model.LstWebAssets is null. It does not capture the file info from the view.

I can capture the files from Request.Files, but that does not provide the other file details like AssetId, IsPreview value.

Please suggest how I will be able to capture the list in the controller. I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest a better way to achieve this functionality in the UI.

Comment: Could please post the controller signature as well? Also where are you calling the post from your view? Are you using a form and submitting, are you doing an ajax call or some other way?

Comment: @A.sharif This code is part of the form and I am submitting the form as a full post, not ajax call.

Comment: Can you check `PdfFile` in `WebEmail` after posting the form, and what data do you get there - do you get bound data there as expected?

Comment: Yes.The file is bound to the pdffile in webemail. I removed it from my parent model and tested. The lstWebAssets is still null.